# SelectedItem not getting value

Tags: c#, xml

I am reading data from a .xml file, inside my C# winforms project, and I can't seem to get the value I am reading to assign to a combo box. The code that doesn't work is here:

```
if (Reader.Name == "BaudRate")
{
    int BaudRate;
    //Reading the node.
    Reader.Read();
    //Making the Baud Rate box equal to the .xml file.
    BaudRate = int.Parse(Reader.Value);
    //Making the combo box equal to the value of the reader.
    BaudRatebx.SelectedItem = BaudRate;
    //Setting the ApplicationPort to the Reader.Value.
    MainBoxWindow.ApplicationPort.BaudRate = BaudRate;
}
```

Although, I have this code that is working perfectly.

```
if (Reader.Name == "Parity")
{
    //Reading the node.
    Reader.Read();
    //Making the Parity box equal to the .xml file.
    Paritybx.SelectedItem = Reader.Value;
    //Setting the ApplicationPort to the Reader.Value.
    MainBoxWindow.ApplicationPort.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), Reader.Value);
}
```

I am not entirely sure what is happening. When I run the program `Reader.Value` has the correct value, and it will populate `BaudRate` with the value, but BaudRate will not assign the value to `BaudRate.SelectedItem`. It just comes out as a null value. Anyone ideas? I have tried `To.String()` and that doesn't help, so i'm not sure what's happening.

Comment: Your code suggests that you are pre-loading `BaudRateBx.Items`.  True?  If so, the `SelectedItem` must _precisely_ match one of them or it will not select.  Perhaps the Parity one matches an Item while Baud does not?  Keep in mind that `(Int32)10` does not equal "10".  One is a number, the other is not.  BTW...WinForms or WPF?

Comment: What do you mean by "insert"? Do you mean that the combo box is empty and you put in stuff as you encounter it though the XML? In that case, `BaudRatebx` does not have any items and the operation `BaudRatebx.SelectedItem` is invalid. You must use the add item functionality. I can't give you any code because i am not sure if this is WPF or forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if the item type is the problem:

```
if (Reader.Name == "BaudRate")
{
    Reader.Read();
    Int32 BaudRate;
    if (Int32.TryParse(Reader.Value, out BaudRate))
    {
        BaudRatebx.SelectedItem = BaudRate.ToString();
        MainBoxWindow.ApplicationPort.BaudRate = BaudRate;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, now I am fairly new to C#. Why did this act differently then me using just `int`?

Comment: Depends on how you add the items, really, but essentially the items were `String` type and not `Int32`.  So the equality test failed.  I think `ComboBox.Items` is an `Object[]`, meaning you have to take care what you add because it will happily accept about anything, but then you'll get weird results later when you ask for it back or try to compare it to something else, unless you're very careful.